# Google Play In-App Purchase returns error code -1008: null puchaseData or dataSignature

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I am attempting to implement [Google Play in-app purchase v3](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html), after successfully implementing it in v2. However, every single time I attempt to purchase one of my real in-app products, I receive the following follow-up error:

IAB returned null purchaseData or dataSignature (response -1008:Unknown error)

This is coming from the [IabHelper.java class, line 452](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/v3/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/IabHelper.java?r=5f6b7abfd0534acd5bfc7c14436f4500c99e0358#452):

```
if (purchaseData == null || dataSignature == null) {
    logError("BUG: either purchaseData or dataSignature is null.");
    logDebug("Extras: " + data.getExtras().toString());
    result = new IabResult(IABHELPER_UNKNOWN_ERROR, "IAB returned null purchaseData or dataSignature");
    if (mPurchaseListener != null) mPurchaseListener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
    return true;
}
```

I have verified that a) my app is signed, b) the version of my app matches the draft version # on the Google Play store, and c) the user attempting the purchase has been added as a test user. I have tried this across 3 test accounts and 4 in-app purchase subscription types.

- Should I be concerned about this error code?
- Is this an issue confined only to non-production releases?
- Will this affect my customers in the field if/when I release this version?
- Can you really only test in-app purchase end-to-end once you actually published it live with IAB version 3? I realize I can use the android.test.purchased item type, and I have (it works), but I don't consider that a valid end-to-end test.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I had this problem myself. After a while I found what I did wrong. I was calling the wrong method on the IABHelper.

If you call `mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(...)` with an SKU that is  registered as a subscription on Google Developer Console it will result in the error:
IAB returned null purchaseData or dataSignature (response -1008:Unknown error).

If you have a SKU that is registered as an subscription you have to use the method: `mHelper.launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow(...)` instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: THANK YOU! That was it. Google Play developer did reply but never got back to me with the solution. I owe you one (literally)!

Comment: I got the same error though i am using the correct item type and method. In-App purchases works, subscriptions not.

Comment: launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow() method in turn calls launchPurchaseFlow() with itemType as 'IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_INAPP'. So if you pass correct itemType in launchPurchaseFlow(), it makes no difference. I am using correct item type, but still getting the same error!!!!

Comment: Boom! So nice to see this answer, I was worried I'd be debugging this for hours.

Comment: Sree -- incorrect, launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow() calls launchPurchaseFlow() with itemType IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_SUBS.

Answer (score 1):

> error purchasing: iabResult: IAB returned null purchase Data or data
>   Signature (response: -1008 unknown error)

if you get above error when you use launchPurchaseFlow() method and get this error check your product type. i was created subscriptions but i needed managed products for example Non-consumable product type. I mean be carefully about buying or subscriptions

Answer (score 1):

For Cordova and Hybrid apps you need to use `this.iap.subscribe(this.productId)` method to subscription `InAppPurchase`.

Following are the code working fine for me:

```
 getProdutIAP() {
        this.navCtrl.push('subscribeDialogPage');
        this.iap
            .getProducts(['productID1']).then((products: any) => {
                this.buy(products);
                // alert('getProdutIAP' + JSON.stringify(products));
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                alert('Finished Purchase' + JSON.stringify(err));
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    buy(products: any) {
        // this.getProdutIAP();
        // alert(products[0].productId);
        this.iap.subscribe(products[0].productId).then((buydata: any) => {
            alert('buy Purchase' + JSON.stringify(buydata));
            // this.sub();
        }).catch((err) => {
            // this.navCtrl.push('subscribeDialogPage');
            alert('buyError' + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    }

    sub() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.iap
                .subscribe(this.productId)
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log('subscribe Purchase' + JSON.stringify(data));
                    alert('subscribe Purchase' + JSON.stringify(data));
                    this.getReceipt();
                }).catch((err) => {
                    this.getReceipt();
                    alert('subscribeError' + JSON.stringify(err));
                    console.log(err);
                });
        })
    }
```