# Android IAB What does code -1008 mean?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

As the title says, I'm getting this error when querying the inventory.

> Failed to query inventory: IabResult: NullPointer while refreshing inventory. (response: -1008:Unknown error)

Someone knows for what this error is standing for?

Comment: Seems like a known bug, you need to catch Exceptions yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15489975/603270

Comment: Could this be relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797663/android-in-app-billing-error-you-need-to-sign-into-your-google-account

Comment: @shkschneider: I allready included this, but still getting this error. But thx for the tip :)

Comment: @Michal: I'm not sure. I was able to buy the product from Google. But if I query the inventory i just get the error. But if I try to rebuy the item it says: Item allready owned, as I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(....)` with an SKU that is registered as a subscription in your Google Developer Console it will result in the error. It means either purchaseData or dataSignature is null.

Check IabHelper.java

```
   if (purchaseData == null || dataSignature == null) {
                logError("BUG: either purchaseData or dataSignature is null.");
                logDebug("Extras: " + data.getExtras().toString());
                result = new IabResult(IABHELPER_UNKNOWN_ERROR, "IAB returned null purchaseData or dataSignature");
                if (mPurchaseListener != null) mPurchaseListener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
                return true;
            }
```

If you have a SKU that is registered as an subscription you have to use the method: `mHelper.launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow(....)`

Also check this answer: [Google Play In-App Purchase returns error code -1008: null puchaseData or dataSignature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377755/google-play-in-app-purchase-returns-error-code-1008-null-puchasedata-or-datasi)

Comment: My SKU is registered as a managed Object. But thx for the reply, I will try.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with my subscriptions because I haven't set the "itemType"

```
 mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this,
            SKU_INFINITE_GAS, IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_SUBS,
            RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```